# Non-scalar cast: `T` as `f64` when doing generic multiplication

Tags: casting, rust, traits

I want to implement a trait for a generic-type struct. A method inside the trait block must return a non-generic type. I'm having problems while trying to cast:

```
struct Rectangle<T> {
    x: T,
    y: T,
    width: T,
    height: T,
}

trait Area {
    fn area(&self) -> f64;
}

impl<T> Area for Rectangle<T>
    where T: std::ops::Mul<Output=T> 
{
    fn area(&self) -> f64 {
        let t_area = self.height * self.width;
        let f_area = t_area as f64;
        f_area
    }
}

fn main() {
    let sq = Rectangle { x: 0, y: 0, height: 1, width: 1 };
    println!("{}", sq.area());
}
```

And the compiler output is:

```
error: non-scalar cast: `T` as `f64`
  --> src/main.rs:22:22
   |
22 |         let f_area = t_area as f64;
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Can I cast `T` to `f64` without using unsafe blocks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I, not using unsafe blocks, cast `T` to `f64`?

What's `T`? The code to convert `u8` to `f64` is certainly not the same as the code to convert `u64` to `f64` (the latter can fail, after all).

As I see it, you have two paths ahead of you:

- make `Area` generic over `T`, and thus return a `T`
- constrain `T` to types that can be converted into a `f64`

I'll demonstrate the latter:

```
impl<T> Area for Rectangle<T>
    where T: std::ops::Mul<Output=T> + Clone + std::convert::Into<f64>
{
    fn area(&self) -> f64 {
        self.height.clone().into() * self.width.clone().into()
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be noted, that `Into` just represents conversions into a subtype of the original type (those that can never loose precision). But I'd say that in this case the programmer probably doesn't care if `u64` or `i64` areas are being cast to `f64` with possible precision loss... Maybe they do, though.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt: I can't know for sure. If [`TryInto`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryInto.html) was stable I would advised it.

Answer (score 3):

> Can I, not using unsafe blocks, cast `T` to `f64`?

**No,** and there are many good reasons for that. `T` could be any type, so it doesn't need to be compatible with or similar to `f64` *at all*. The only thing you know about your `T` is, that it implements `std::ops::Mul<Output=T>`. But that doesn't help, because that trait doesn't say anything about `f64` either.

So what you *could* do, is to bound `T` to be `std::ops::Mul<Output=f64>`. This means that multiplying two `T`s will result in an `f64`. Your function then works (even without the `as f64` cast), but you make your impl way less generic.

---

The proper way to solve this problem, is to abstract over multiple kinds of numbers. Thankfully, the [`num-traits` crate](https://crates.io/crates/num-traits) has already done that. In particular, you are probably interested in the [`ToPrimitive` trait](http://rust-num.github.io/num/num_traits/cast/trait.ToPrimitive.html). Your impl should then probably look somewhat like:

```
use num_traits::ToPrimitive;

impl<T> Area for Rectangle<T>
    where T: std::ops::Mul
          <T as std::ops::Mul>::Output: ToPrimitive

{
    fn area(&self) -> f64 {
        let t_area = self.height * self.width;
        t_area.to_f64().unwrap()
    }
}
```

Minor problem: we have this `unwrap()` here which panics when the multiplication result can't be converted into an `f64`. I'm not quite sure why this can happen, but we need to be aware of that. Maybe there is a better solution without such an `unwrap()`.

---

You can of course also create your own trait. Something like:

```
trait AsF64 {
    fn cast(self) -> f64;
}

impl AsF64 for i32 {
    fn cast(self) -> f64 { self as f64 }
}

// more impls for u32, u16, i16, ...
```

And then impl for `<T as std::ops::Mul>::Output: AsF64`.